# I am attempting to create a program that will determine if a password is one of the top 10 most popular using 'not in'

Tags: python

```
invalidPassword = ["123456","123456789","qwerty","password","111111","12345678","abc123","1234567","password1","12345"]

print ("Choose a strong password.")
newpassword = input()

if newpassword not in invalidPassword
  print("This will be your password for 90 days.")

elif newpassword in invalidPassword
  print("No, that is not a strong password.")
```

[Screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4prr.png)

Answer (score 1):

You missing `:` after the if statement

also you can put the printed value inside the input function

```py
print ("Choose a strong password.")
newpassword = input()
```

can be writted as:

```py
newpassword = input("Choose a strong password.")
```

Comment: Clearly too tired for simple homework today. Thank you for solving my idiocy.

Comment: @claspina27 That word "homework" is gonna get you into trouble in here, if you intend to stay on StackOverflow :)